# parse txt with different types in string

Tags: scala, parsing, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I have txt files with semistructured data, I have to write it in cassandra through spark-cassandra. But for the first I what to parse in only in scala.

my code :

```
import java.io.File
import scala.io.Source

object parser extends App {
  val path = "somepath"
  val fileArray = (new java.io.File(path)).listFiles()
   for (file <- fileArray)
    for (line <- Source.fromFile(file).getLines())
```

So how can I parse each string and get values to put it in cassandra?
for example I have (int, text, timestamp, int, text, char, int, text)?
I have to split line for delimiter(" ")? and put them in a tuple? or each of them to convert to readable format?

Answer (score 0):

What you probably could do is to handle it as csv file with delimiter(" ")? So let Spark do the parsing for you.

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf).getOrCreate()
val dataFrame = spark.read.option("inferSchema", "true").option("delimiter", " ").csv(csvfilePath)
```